# collect TRs from html table to csv, using python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, tr

so i tried many ways;
I want to collect a outages tables from Hydro website.
then store it in csv as table.

i checked normally the tr has 3 td (except the header, was getting error, so i did put if to count tr tds if equal to 3.
but somehow with beautifulsoup it detect only 1 td.
after got to put it in csv :
a,b,c
d,e,f...

code :

```
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://poweroutages.hydroquebec.com/poweroutages/service-interruption-report/#bis'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')
print(table)
rates = {}
for tr in soup('tr'):

    if len(tr('td')) == 3:
        region_td, interruptions_td, cx_td = tr('td')
        print('hello')
        region = print(region_td)('i')[0]['title']
        interruptions = float(interruptions_td.text)
        cx = print(cx_td)('i')[0]['title']
        rates[region] = [interruptions, cx]
```

output or result :

```
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://poweroutages.hydroquebec.com/poweroutages/service-interruption-report/#bis'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')
print(table)
rates = {}
for tr in soup('tr'):

    if len(tr('td')) == 3:
        region_td, interruptions_td, cx_td = tr('td')
        print('hello')
        region = print(region_td)('i')[0]['title']
        interruptions = float(interruptions_td.text)
        cx = print(cx_td)('i')[0]['title']
        rates[region] = [interruptions, cx]
```

the other way i tried worked, but was able to put all in one array, and the footer has 2 tds instead of 3.
code 2 :

```
import requests
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://poweroutages.hydroquebec.com/poweroutages/service-interruption-report/#bis'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

n_interruptions = [i.text for i in soup.findAll('td')]

outageqc = pd.DataFrame({
    "n_interruptions": n_interruptions

})

outageqc.set_index('n_interruptions', inplace=True)

print(outageqc)
x = len(outageqc) / 3
```

output :

> Index: [Abitibi-Témiscamingue, 0, 0 customer out of 81 377,
> Bas-Saint-Laurent, 0, 0 customer out of 123 929, Capitale-Nationale,
> 6, 2 589 customers out of 424 080, Centre-du-Québec, 28, 3 547
> customers out of 140 391, Chaudière-Appalaches, 14, 3 384 customers
> out of 244 321, Côte-Nord, 0, 0 customer out of 48 101, Estrie, 44, 1
> 684 customers out of 90 947, Gaspésie - Îles-de-la-Madeleine, 0, 0
> customer out of 57 355, Lanaudière, 9, 240 customers out of 255 267,
> Laurentides, 3, 51 customers out of 350 118, Laval, 5, 939 customers
> out of 193 619, Mauricie, 19, 4 251 customers out of 165 191,
> Montréal, 4, 1 067 customers out of 1 058 896, Montérégie, 61, 9 380
> customers out of 786 889, Nord-du-Québec, 0, 0 customer out of 22 127,
> Outaouais, 6, 71 customers out of 219 701, Saguenay - Lac-Saint-Jean,
> 0, 0 customer out of 130 952, 199, 27 203 customers out of 4 393 261]

this one missed the footer first column.

Comment: Did you try, [`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) which would parse table's and return dataframes.

Comment: thanks Sushanth, am new in py coding:) ,,,,, just tried it and seems less complicated,,,,,took me few moment,,,,but got csv done too; thanks for the Hint ;)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Sushanth for the hint,,,
fixed

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import io
import requests
import pandas as pd
from zipfile import ZipFile

df = pd.read_html('http://poweroutages.hydroquebec.com/poweroutages/service-interruption-report/#bis')

for i, table in enumerate(df):
    table.to_csv('test.csv', ',')
```